# Litegraph.js unable to click on node value

Tags: vue.js

#### Unable to click on const number node value in vue.js

This is code which i'm using to generate a node based ui.

[image]

```
<template>
    <canvas ref="lite_canvas" id='mycanvas' width='1024' height='720' style='border: 1px solid'></canvas>
</template>


<script>
import { LGraph, LGraphCanvas, LiteGraph } from "/node_modules/litegraph.js"

export default {
    mounted() {
        var graph = new LGraph();
        var canvas = new LGraphCanvas("#mycanvas", graph);

        // 2 nodes and a link
        var node_const = LiteGraph.createNode("basic/const");
        node_const.pos = [200, 200];
        graph.add(node_const);
        node_const.setValue(4.5);

        var node_watch = LiteGraph.createNode("basic/watch");
        node_watch.pos = [700, 200];
        graph.add(node_watch);

        node_const.connect(0, node_watch, 0);
        // main
        graph.start()
    }
}

</script>
<style scoped>
@import "https://tamats.com/projects/litegraph/css/litegraph.css";

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width:100%; height:100%;
}

#mycanvas {
  border: 1px solid;
}

button {
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;
}
</style>
```

I have tried multiple things by added inline css added external css but haven't found any solution yet.
Look for response which resolve my issue.